# Uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected string In jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am facing an

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" error while using jquery.

MY function is when I click on the plus icon, a few HTML added.

My code here

```
var content_div = '<br/><div class="row input_fields_wrap testclass"><input type="hidden" id="t_id_'+sb_index+'" name="t_id[]" value='' ><div class="col-md-4"><label>Postcode&nbsp;<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><input type="text" required name="t_postcode[]" id="t_postcode_'+sb_index+'" value="" class="form-control" value="" oninput="" maxlength="8"  placeholder="Postcode"><span id="matchCodeResponse"></span></div><div class="col-md-3"><label>Price&nbsp;<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><input type="text" required name="t_price[]" id="t_price_'+sb_index+'" value="" oninput="" maxlength="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"><span id="matchCodeResponse"></span></div><div class="col-md-4"><label>Area Name&nbsp;<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>  <input type="text" required name="t_location_name[]" id="t_location_name_'+sb_index+'" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Area Name"></div><div class="col-md-1 remove_div"><label>&nbsp;</label><br/><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" style="font-size: 30px;"></i></a></div></div>';
        $(".testclass").last().after(content_div);
```

Comment: You can not use `'` (single quotes) inside a single quoted string without escaping them like `\'`.

Comment: Thanks, find my issue, it's a quote issue.

Answer (score 0):

use string literale to prevent getting error , your var would be embeded using sitring expression like : `${your_var}` ,

See working snipet below :

```js
$(function() {

  $("#btn").on("click", function() {

    var sb_index = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);

    var content_div = `<br/><div class="row input_fields_wrap testclass"><input type="hidden" id="t_id_${sb_index}" name="t_id[]" value='
' ><div class="col-md-4"><label>Postcode&nbsp;<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><input type="text" required name="t_postcode[]" id="t_postcode_${sb_index}" value="" class="form-control" value="" oninput="" maxlength="8"  placeholder="Postcode"><span id="matchCodeResponse"></span></div><div class="col-md-3"><label>Price&nbsp;<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><input type="text" required name="t_price[]" id="t_price_${sb_index}" value="" oninput="" maxlength="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"><span id="matchCodeResponse"></span></div><div class="col-md-4"><label>Area Name&nbsp;<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>  <input type="text" required name="t_location_name[]" id="t_location_name_${sb_index}" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Area Name"></div><div class="col-md-1 remove_div"><label>&nbsp;</label><br/><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" style="font-size: 30px;"></i></a></div></div>`;

    $(".testclass").last().after(content_div);

  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">click to add div</button>



<div class="testclass">
  <div>First test</div>
</div>
```